# Opening link in new window with jquery

Tags: jquery, anchor

Hi I am using the following jquery to make a div cliackable (for page skin ads):

```
$url = "http://google.com";
$("#toLeft,#toRight").click(
    function()
        {
            window.location = $url;
            return false;
        });
```

I need to ensure that when a link is clicked, it is opened in another window. Typically, I use this snippet to make all outside links open in a new window, but it doesnt work with this (due to the jquery generated link):

```
$("a").filter(function() {
                return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
            }).attr('target', '_blank');
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Here are the W3School's docs for window.open, to go with the accepted answer http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)?

Comment: is there an alternate way of doing this? I cant seem to wrap my head around window.open

Comment: very easy to implement actually. It is as simple as: window.open("http://google.com")

Comment: A note on the snippet you normally use: though I haven't fiddled around with it yet, the `hostname` property on anchor tags seems to be HTML5 only [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement)